# Any support library to develop multisite application from single Code Source in yii2 like Wordpress?

Tags: php, yii2

As per my requirements, I am going to develop Custom CMS Application using Yii2. CMS will be having feature to manage multiple websites from single Code source.

So Is there any library available in Yii2 to manage multiple websites?

Please provide your valuable suggestions

Comment: Yii2 have a built-in feature to handle several applications with one core. Read "Applications" under "Advanced Template" here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-advanced-app.html. 
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes Advanced template provides built-in feature to handle several applications. But for every new website I have to edit code source and create new websites. So I need application such that I can create new website from backend and can be managed from backend.

Comment: Ah, okey. I have not heard of anything like that.